# Reference master page stored at root from sub domain folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a folder in the root called secure and I have a sub domain called secure which maps to the secure folder. However, I'm getting the following error:
 `The virtual path '/MasterPage.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.`
Is there a setting somewhere that I can change or some other way to make this work without making a masterpage within the secure folder that has the same data as the root version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your IIS setup a little clearer please. From your description it sounds like you have:

- http://yourserver (root)
- http://yourserver/secure (folder) [is this an application or just a folder?]
- http://secure.yourserver (sub-domain) [maps to same folder as http://yourserver/secure]

**EDIT**

You could store your master pages in a folder

http://yourserver/layouts/MasterPage.master

Then map that folder to your second web site

http://secure.yourserver/layouts

http://secure.yourserver/layouts/MasterPage.master

Then update your page master references to "layouts/MasterPage.master"

Comment: how do I map the layouts folder to the secure subdomain?